# Mongoose doesn't find just saved data

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am using:

- mongoose 4.4.7
- node 4.2.6
- mongodb 3.2.4
- async 1.5.2

My sport schema:

```
var mongoose =  require("mongoose");
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var sportSchema = new Schema ({
    name: { type: Schema.Types.Mixed, required: true},
    provider_id: { type: Number,index: true, unique: true, sparse: true},
    sort: { type: Number, default: -1},
    state: {type:String, default: "stopped",select: false},
    date: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now, select:  false}
})
module.exports = mongoose.model("Sport", sportSchema);
```

My connection file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
var db_name = "project";
if (env === "test") {
    db_name = db_name+"_test";
}
var url = 'mongodb://localhost/'+db_name;
var db_connected = function() {
    console.log("Database " + db_name + " connected");
}
mongoose.connect(url,db_connected);
module.exports = mongoose;
```

This function handles processing of sports which are imported from xml files:

```
function processSport(sport,cb) {
async.waterfall([
    // Look for sport
    function (next) {
        Sport.find({provider_id: sport.provider_id}).limit(1).exec(function(err){
            if (err) {
                console.log("Couldn't find sport:",err)
                return next(err)
            }
        }).then(function(db_sport){
            return next(null,db_sport)
        })
    },
    function(db_sport,next) {
        if (!db_sport.length) {
            //Create sport
            db_sport = new Sport({provider_id: sport.provider_id,name:sport.name});
            db_sport.save(function(err){
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Couldn't save sport:",err)
                        return next(err)
                    }
                }).then(function(db_sport){
                return next(null,db_sport)
            })
           // End create sport
        } else {
            return next(null,db_sport[0])
        }
    }
], function (err,db_sport){
    cb(null,db_sport)
})
}
```

My problem is that if I've got multiple files containing the same 2 sports, the processing is so fast, that just created sports are not found by the `Sport.find()` method.

File handling is as follows:

```
function processByFile(env,files,main_callback) {
async.each(files, function(file,file_callback) {
    var xml = FileHelper.readXMLFile(env, file);
    processFile(xml,file_callback)
}, main_callback())

}

function processFile(xml,file_callback) {
xmlParser(xml, function (err, sports_data) {
    if (err) {
        return file_callback(err)
    } else {
        if (sports_data != null) {
            //Actual processing starts here
            async.each(sports_data, function (sport, sport_callback) {
                processSport(sport,function (err,db_sport){
                    console.log(db_sport._id + "-" +db_sport.provider_id)
                    sport_callback()
                })

            },file_callback())

        }
    }
})

}
```

If I pass in 2 files with two identical sports. The output is the following:

```
//2 duplicate key warnings
56e7e9cf12d821c1b0b4130b-5
56e7e9cf12d821c1b0b4130a-2
```

Before I added the unique index 4 sports were created.

I tried to set the `--syncdelay 0` and `--journalCommitInterval 2` on my mongod instance but it still doesn't find the transient (or what/whereever  they are 2ms after they've been saved and returned by a promise) documents. In production mode files will arrive every 10 seconds, so it's not that big of a problem. But when I when I want to reread a lot of files this can become nasty.

Anybody an idea what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Setting `var mongoose = require('mongoose').set('debug', true);` shows me, that all `finds` are executed before the first insert. So something with the async.waterfall is wrong (i guess).

Answer (score 0):

```
function processPrematchOddsByFile(env,files,main_callback) {
async.eachSeries(files, function(file,file_callback) {
    var xml = FileHelper.readXMLFile(env, file);
    processPrematchOdds(xml,file,file_callback)
}, main_callback())

}
```

`eachSeries`instead of `each`

and

```
function processFile(xml,file_callback) {
xmlParser(xml, function (err, sports_data) {
if (err) {
    return file_callback(err)
} else {
    if (sports_data != null) {
        //Actual processing starts here
        async.each(sports_data, function (sport, sport_callback) {
            processSport(sport,function (err,db_sport){
                console.log(db_sport._id + "-" +db_sport.provider_id)
                sport_callback()
                return file_callback()
            })

        })

    }
}
})

}
```

`file_callback()` in sport processing as this is the toplevel of the parsed xml document.

This did the trick. Now queries come in expected order, everything is working as expected.